# Use of set -e in BASH

Tags: bash

I wanted to know if it was possible to code that kind of line in a BASH program
I would like to have something that looks like:

```
if set -e
    echo "Error"
fi
```

Actually my teacher just told that set -e stops the program when there is an error. I don't really know how it works. What I want is that when there is an error at any part of the program it does `echo "Error"`

I'm just learning how to use bash so my knowledge isn't very good yet.

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is that when there is an error at any part of the program
>   it does echo "Error"

You can use a trap:

```
trap "echo Error" ERR
cat ./file_that_doesnt_exist
echo "something after the error"
```

If you use this in combination with `set -e` the program will display the message and immediately exit - i.e. the echo won't run.

Comment: Actually my teacher just told that set -e stops the program when there is an error. I don't really know how it works. What I want is that when there is an error at any part of the program it does `echo "Error" `

Comment: Ah, bad memory on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a `trap` handler to execute custom code.

```
set -e
trap 'echo "Error $?"' ERR

...

# Simulate a command that fails by calling `exit` in a subshell.
(exit 3)
```